# MATLAB: How to ignore NaN values in the KMEDOIDS Function?

Tags: matlab

I have multidimensional dataset with NaN values and my goal is to perform cluster analysis using k-medoids clustering algorithm.

I use correlation as distance metric, but each time I run the function (kmedoids), only ~60% of data are assigned to a cluster due to missing data points.

Is there an option to ignore NaN values and calculate correlation ignoring NaN values when there are at least 2 data points to compare?

Interpolation is not appropriate method in this case.

Comment: I know this is a late answer, but you when using `kmedoids` you can supply a custom distance function that implements what you want the distance to be in the presence of missing data.